# Network traffic through a particular port using iftop

Tags: networking, network-programming, wireshark

I have a process using https. I found its PID using `ps` and used the command `lsof -Pan -p PID -i` to get the port number it is running on.

I need iftop to see the data transfer. The filter I am using now is 
`iftop -f "port http 57787"`.

I don't think this is giving me the right output. 
Can someone help me the right filter to use with iftop so that I know the traffic going through only this port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see 2 problems here:

1/ Is that a typo? The correct option for filtering is -f (small "f"). -F (capital "F") option is for net/mask.

2/ Though not explicitly stated by `iftop` documentation, the syntax for filtering seems to be the `pcap` one from the few examples given (and using `ldd` I can see that yes, the `iftop` binary is linked with `libpcap`). So a filter with `http` is simply not valid. To see the doc for `pcap` filtering syntax, have a look at `pcap-filter (7) - packet filter syntax` man page. In your example, a filter such as "tcp port 57787" would be OK. `pcap` does not do layer 5 and above protocol dissection such as http (pcap filters are handled by BPF in the kernel, so above layer 4 you're on your own, because that's none of the kernel business).

<strike>All in all, these looks like `iperf` bugs. It should refuse your "-F" option, and even with "-f" instead exit with an error code because `pcap` will refuse the filter expression. No big deal, `iftop` is a modest program.</strike> See edit bellow.

EDIT:

I just checked iftop version 1.0pre4 source code, and there is no such obvious bug from a look at `set_filter_code()` and its caller `packet_init()` in `iftop.c`. It correctly exit with error, but...

**Error 2, use the "-f" option, but your incorrect filter syntax:**

```
jbm@sumo:~$ sudo iftop -f "port http 57787"
interface: eth0
IP address is: 192.168.1.67
MAC address is: 8c:89:a5:57:10:3c
set_filter_code: syntax error
```

That's OK.

**Error 1, the "-F" instead of "-f", there is a problem:**

```
jbm@sumo:~$ sudo iftop -F "port http 57787"
```

(everything seems more or less OK, but then quit the program)

```
Could not parse net/mask: port http 57787
interface: eth0
IP address is: 192.168.1.67
MAC address is: 8c:89:a5:57:10:3c
```

Oops! "Could not parse net/mask: port http 57787"! That's a bug: it should exit right away.

Comment: Is there a way I can see the traffic for all tcp ports?

Comment: @nidhimj22 Sure. `sudo iftop -f "tcp"` _Do_ read the pcap-filter man page as I suggested above. It's an investment you'll be able to re-use with `tcpdump`, `wireshark`, `dumpcap`...

Comment: I realised the port on which my process is running is changing( I have no idea why) .. Is there a way I can include all http ports and/or all https ports.

Comment: I am trying to see the difference in performance between HTTP and HTTPS. HTTPS is performing better. I want to see the received data to see if HTTPS is performing some compression that is resulting in the improved efficiency or is there something else. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @nidhimj22 There is no such thing as "http" ports. Ports are for layer 4 (tcp or udp), http is a layer 5 protocol. If you need to specify an protocol, you'll need a higher level tool, that does not only capture but also protocol dissection. `pcap`, at it's level, does only capture and filtering up to layer 4, as I explained. Example of tools that do protocol dissection above `pcap` include `tcpdump` (quite limited dissection) and `wireshark` (very powerful). Look around or even do your own using libs that leverage on pcap, such as scapy.

Comment: @nidhimj22 "I realised the port on which my process is running is changing( I have no idea why)" probably because your process is a client, using what is called an "ephemeral port " chosen randomly by the TCP/IP implementation in the kernel. As opposed to a server, which listen on a fixed port.